# Seriously, serial down voting?

Tags: discussion

After coming back and briefly jump back in the game, I get hit with serial down voting?

I waited to see if the system would automatically catch it, and it did, but I wanted to clearly state that I'm willing to debate both my opinions on meta, and content on the main site should anyone wish to discuss them openly.

Further I'm willing to be convinced of different view points or that I am wrong.  Serial down voting doesn't seem to be productive on any level, and serves to discourage users (not that I actually feel discouraged).

Answer (score 4):

I think serial downvoting should be much more severely punished. As of now, one can cast a dozen of downvotes to someone, and have no issue. This kind of behavior doesn't help attracting contributions.

Comment: Yeah, down-voting in general is hurting health.SE, I think we all need to go a little more easy on the dv's and strive for more clarity in communication.

Comment: That's called serial downvoting and SE will usually detect it and undo those downvotes. Continuing the targeted downvoting will usually result in increasingly harsh penalties.

Comment: What constitutes "serial" downvoting? Within a span of an hour, all three of my latest questions were downvoted. I do recognize that one of my questions could have been better so I didn't think anything at first, but then soon following, my other questions were downvoted without explanation. I'm not overly concern, I'm just curious as to what point "serial" downvoting triggers the system? Is it through questions on meta that a flag is raised? (maybe this should have been a question unto it's own.... sorry).

Comment: @ButterflyandBones "to what point "serial" downvoting triggers the system" -> more than three downvotes in the same day by the same person, I believe.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for brining this to our attention. Targeted voting is certainly not appropriate, although it is difficult to "prove" whether this was done with malicious intent. In this case, the serial voting pattern was clarified by the Community Team and appropriate action has been taken in regard to the individual(s) involved.